# Excel Macro Unable to Separate String Address

Tags: regex, vba, excel

**Software:** MS Excel 2016

---

#### Update 1

Please note there can be any number of digits before West, i.e.

`123124234234West18th Street`

`2West 14th Avenue`

`12324West`

Please assist with general solution

---

---

#### Original Question

There is address, `31West  52nd Street` I am trying to split the `31` and `West` so output will be

`31 West 52nd Street`

Tried this Macro statement but it won't work, please guide

`Selection.Replace What:="?@West  ", Replacement:=" West " _
        , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat _
        :=False, ReplaceFormat:=False`

Comment: Can you list all possible address that you have? or is just this one with `west` text in it?

Comment: Hello @GowthamShiva, I updated question. There can be different number of digits before `West`

Comment: You have an answer already. That should help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample of code, that would check for the first few chars. If they are digits, if would split them with a space from the rest:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print fnStrStripMyNumber("31West  52nd Street")
    Debug.Print fnStrStripMyNumber("123Vityata Shampion")

End Sub

Public Function fnStrStripMyNumber(strStr As String) As String

    Dim lngCountDigits  As Long
    Dim lngCounter      As Long

    strStr = Trim(strStr)

    For lngCounter = 1 To Len(strStr)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strStr, lngCounter, 1)) Then
            lngCountDigits = lngCountDigits + 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    strStr = Left(strStr, lngCountDigits) & " " & Right(strStr, Len(strStr) - lngCountDigits)
    fnStrStripMyNumber = Trim(strStr)

End Function
```

Thus, from input:

```
"31West  52nd Street"
"123Vityata Shampion"
```

We get output:

```
31 West  52nd Street
123 Vityata Shampion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this excel formula as well,

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("West",A1)-1)&" "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("West",A1)+1)
```

[image]

Or if you want a macro only,

```
Sub rep()
Range("B1") = Replace(Range("A1"), "West", " West")
End Sub
```